# Extracting queries from a URL

Tags: python, url

I'm trying to write a method that will extract the query parameters from a URL (`php?id=2`, `admin?id=34&page=2`, etc..). What I have so far will do just that unless the php part doesn't have a `.` for example it will work on `https://example.com/subcat.php?id=2` but not on `http://examples2.com/php?admin=2`.

```
def obtain_inject_query(url):
    queries = url.split("?")
    data = queries[0].rsplit(".")[-1]
    print ''.join(data) + "?" + queries[1]
    # obtain_inject_query("https://example.com/admin?qt=123&america=1234")
    # <= com/admin?qt=123&america=1234
    # obtain_inject_query("https://example.com/subcat.admin?qt=123&america=1234")
    # <= admin?qt=123&america=1234
```

How can I fix this to where it will only extract the query and not the `com` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the `urlparse` module:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://examples2.com/php?admin=2')
>>> o
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='examples2.com', path='/php', params='', query='admin=2', fragment='')
>>> o.query
'admin=2'
```

Comment: I didn't even know that existed

Comment: If you are using Python 3 use `urllib.parse`, the docs are located [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse).